# Pimcore exception when listing objects

Tags: zend-framework, mysqli, pimcore

I get an Pimcore exception on my Server (but not local) at the Line:

```
$entries = new Object\CarouselImage\Listing();
```

The Exception with Stacktrace is:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Zend_Db_Statement_Mysqli_Exception' with message 'Mysqli statement execute error : 
Prepared statement needs to be re-prepared' in /www/doc/www.eastmeetswest.eu/www/pimcore/lib/Zend/Db/Statement/Mysqli.php:214 
Stack trace: 
#0 /www/doc/www.eastmeetswest.eu/www/pimcore/lib/Zend/Db/Statement.php(303): Zend_Db_Statement_Mysqli->_execute(Array) 
#1 /www/doc/www.eastmeetswest.eu/www/pimcore/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(480): Zend_Db_Statement->execute(Array) 
#2 /www/doc/www.eastmeetswest.eu/www/pimcore/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(737): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->query('SELECT object_6...', Array) 
#3 [internal function]: Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->fetchAll('SELECT object_6...', Array) 
#4 /www/doc/www.eastmeetswest.eu/www/pimcore/lib/Pimcore/Resource/Wrapper.php(263): call_user_func_array(Array, Array) 
#5 /www/doc/www.eastmeetswest.eu/www/pimcore/lib/Pimcore/Resource/Wrapper.php(233): Pimcore\Resource\Wrapper->callResourceMethod('fetchAll', Array) 
#6 /www/doc/www.eastmeetswest.eu/www/pimcore/ in /www/doc/www.eastmeetswest.eu/www/pimcore/lib/Zend/Db/Statement/Mysqli.php on line 214
```

The exact same code does everything it should do on the localhost and if I iterate over the objects with:

```
$entry = Object_CarouselImage::getById($id);
```

everything works fine.

Comment: Edit: I know that this could be a " known issue with some MySQL servers." but is there any workaround than restarting the server.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably the easiest solution would be to switch to Pdo_Mysql.
Change this line in /website/var/config/system.xml under **database** node

```
<adapter>Pdo_Mysql</adapter>
```

This might cause some other problems though so test thoroughly after switching.

Comment: Any ideas why does the adapter change solves this issue? What's the problem with Mysqli?

Comment: This doesn't actually solve the issue but circumvents it. Pdo_Mysql is an alternative to Mysqli and both have similar functionalities with few differences. The original issue could be caused by a bug in that particular version of MySQL, mysqli or in configuration of MySQL. If InnoDB is disabled it might cause this problem as described here: https://xenforo.com/community/threads/error-on-install.17901/